# Are there have a library (any language) to parse the nginx.conf to object?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a problem to parse the nginx.conf into memory object, and load them in to a WebUI, user can modify the configuration on the WebUI and save it as a new nginx.conf to replace the old one, then reload the nginx.

But Parsing the nginx.conf is too hard, are there have a good library can help to do this work efficiently?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use crossplane as a python module and get your conf in json :
https://github.com/nginxinc/crossplane

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it ~